# Understanding DB Connection Pools in python

Tags: python, database, multithreading, connection-pooling, fork

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the use case for DB connection pools (eg: psycopg2.pool and mysql.connector.pooling) in python. It seems to me that parallelism is usually achieved in python using a multi-process rather than a multi-thread approach because of the GIL, and that in the multi-process case these pools are not very useful since each process will initialize its own pool and will only have a single thread running at a time. Is this correct? Is there any strategy for sharing a DB connection pool when using multiple processes, and if not is the usefulness of pooling limited to multi-threaded python applications or are there other scenarios where you would use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keith,

You're on the right track. As mentioned in the S.O post "[Accessing a MySQL connection pool from Python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374058/accessing-a-mysql-connection-pool-from-python-multiprocessing),":

```
Making a seperate pool for each process is redundant and opens up way
too many connections.
```

Check out the other S.O post, "[What is the best solution for database connection pooling in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98687/what-is-the-best-solution-for-database-connection-pooling-in-python)", it contains a sample pooling solution in python. This post also discusses the limitations of db-pooling if your application were to become multi-threaded:

```
Making your own connection pool is a BAD idea if your app ever decides to start using 
multi-threading. Making a connection pool for a multi-threaded application is much 
more complicated than one for a single-threaded application. You can use something 
like PySQLPool in that case.
```

In-terms of implementing db pooling in python, as mentioned in "[Application vs Database Resident Connection Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848191/application-vs-database-resident-connection-pool?rq=1)," if your database supports it, the best implementation would involve:

```
Let connection pool be maintained and managed by database itself 
(example: Oracle's DRCP) and calling modules just ask connections from the connection 
broker described by Oracle DRCP.
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!